# How to write lists generated through for loop into one list?

Tags: python

I have written a one hot encoding program and the current output is separate lists (which are generated through the `for` loop below):

```python
onehot_encoded = list()
for value in integer_encoded:
    base = [0 for x in range(len(bases))]
    base[value] = 1
    onehot_encoded.extend(base)
print(onehot_encoded)
```

So far the example output looks like this, where one base is encoded per list:

```python
[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
```

Whereas I would like it to be written into one list of lists like so:

```python
[[[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

I have tried to create a list to which `onehot_encoded` outputs would be appended, but this does not work:

```python
masterlist = list()    
onehot_encoded = list()
for value in integer_encoded:
    base = [0 for x in range(len(bases))]
    base[value] = 1
    onehot_encoded.extend(base)
masterlist.append(onehot_encoded)
print(masterlist)
```

I would really appreciate any help in identifying where I am going wrong. I am a beginner in Python, and am finding it hard to identify the flaw in logic here.

EDIT: `bases = "ACTG"`, so each base needs 4 integers to be encoded, e.g."AG" would be `[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]`. 
`integer_encoded` is an earlier piece of code, where `bases` is enumerated, so the input sequence is encoded as integers, for example: "AG" in this case would be "0, 3"

Comment: Your code seems strange to me. With `base = [0 for x in range(len(bases))]` you are repeatedly creating lists.
Is that your complete code and copy-pasted output?

Comment: No, this is just the relevant section of code, as the program is quite a bit longer than this. I have written the outputs as examples to show what I would like it to look like - there are four bases, so for example ```[1, 0, 0, 0]``` could mean "A" and ```[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]``` could mean "AC". And yes, the lists need to be created repeatedly - I am encoding DNA sequences, and one list is created per sequence. I am just looking for a way to place all these lists into one list.

Comment: it might be helpful to add a sample for bases and integer_encoded to the question

Comment: Please see edited answer based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

try using `append` instead of `extend`

```
    onehot_encoded.append(base)
```

`extend` enlarges initial array with items from `base` while `append` puts `base` as it is

Comment: Thank you, but for my purpose it needs to be ```extend```, because I need each sequence that I am encoding to be on the same line and in the same list. ```append```produces lots of separate lists which is not the format I need

Comment: Actually base is a list with one element if We use append output is like : [[1],[0],[0],[1],[0],[1]]

Comment: `base = [0 for x in range(len(bases))]` makes a list of zeros and equivalent to
`base = [0] * len(bases)` and has the same length as bases do

Comment: ```bases = "ACTG"```, so each base needs 4 integers to be encoded, e.g. "AG" would be ```[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]```

Comment: with your code yes. but you use `append` it would become [[1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]

Comment: Yes @alexey, but this is not the format I need - ```extend``` already produces the desired format.

Comment: if you need to stack values from one list you can use a list comprehension:
`[x for encoding onehot_encoded for x in encoding]`

Answer (score 0):

To get a list of lists, you likely need two nested loops (there are ways around it, but likely inconvenient).

**EDIT**: You did not show a specific case where you specify the input for your snippet, and the corresponding expected output.
Assuming from your comment (which is not complete but helps in this respect),

Input:

```
bases = "ACTG"
integer_encoded = [ "CA", "CT" ]
```

Expected output:

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]
```

This code produces the result:

```
bases = "ACTG"
#integer_encoded_pairs = [ "CA", "CT" ]
integer_encoded_pairs = [ "10", "12" ]

masterlist = list()
for integer_encoded in integer_encoded_pairs:
    onehot_encoded = list()
    for value in integer_encoded:
        base = [0 for x in range(len(bases))]
        base[int(value)] = 1
        onehot_encoded.extend(base)
    masterlist.append(onehot_encoded)
print(masterlist)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this?

```
#sample data
bases = ["AG", "A"]
integer_encoded = [[0,3],[0]]

masterlist = list()  

for encode in integer_encoded:  
    onehot_encoded = list()
    for value in encode:
        base = [0 for x in range(4)]
        base[value] = 1
        onehot_encoded.extend(base)
    masterlist.append(onehot_encoded)
```

`print(masterlist)` will give you the required output `[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1], [1, 0, 0, 0]]`

Comment: Thank you @astrosyam but this does not address my issue of placing the ```onehot_encoded``` lists generated into one list. There are multiple input sequences being put through this program, and I am trying to put all the lists generated through the above one hot encoder into one list, as shown in the example in the question:```[[0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]]```

Comment: what is the shape of integer_encoded? is it like ...bases = ["AG", "A"]
integer_encoded = [[0,3],[0]]